# How can I improve the performance of Skyrim on Mac using Wineskin?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, macos, wine

I use a Mac as a gaming device with the help of Wineskin wrappers that allow PC games to run on Mac.

I've installed Oblivion through Wineskin. Oblivion works well on the highest possible setting on my early 2010 MacBook Pro 13" with an Nvidia 320M 256 MB graphics card. I've tried to install Skyrim, but even on the lowest settings, Skyrim look much worse than Oblivion did, it runs at 5 FPS, and has no sound whatsoever.

How can I get Skyrim to at least work at 30 FPS and have sound?

Comment: Migrate to superuser?

Answer (score 2):

Third party programs that try to interpret an OS will ALWAYS be problematic. I would suggest asking for help on a forum specific to that Wineskin wrapper you are using. Or set up a dual boot for windows and use the second OS as your game OS until Mac gets more support.

Comment: Dual boot is a safe shout.

Comment: Yes - just don't bother. Run it in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Use CrossOver, or use Parallels Desktop/VMWare Fusion/VirtualBox. The best solution is always to dual boot, though.